# Очень медленно определяются координаты gps

Tags: java, android, gps

координат приходится по пол часа ждать... как ускорить процесс?
вроде всё помануалам делал

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dp">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvTitleGPS"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/provider_gps"
        android:textSize="30sp">
    </TextView>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvEnabledGPS"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="24sp">
    </TextView>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvStatusGPS"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="24sp">
    </TextView>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvLocationGPS"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="24sp">
    </TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

**activity_main**

```
package com.example.test.location;
import java.util.Date;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

  TextView tvEnabledGPS;
  TextView tvStatusGPS;
  TextView tvLocationGPS;
  TextView tvEnabledNet;
  TextView tvStatusNet;
  TextView tvLocationNet;

  private LocationManager locationManager;
  StringBuilder sbGPS = new StringBuilder();

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    tvEnabledGPS = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvEnabledGPS);
    tvStatusGPS = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvStatusGPS);
    tvLocationGPS = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvLocationGPS);


    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
            1000 * 10, 10, locationListener);
    checkEnabled();
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);
  }

  private LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
      showLocation(location);
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
      checkEnabled();
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
      checkEnabled();
      showLocation(locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider));
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
      if (provider.equals(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
        tvStatusGPS.setText("Status: " + String.valueOf(status));
      }
    }
  };

  private void showLocation(Location location) {
    if (location == null)
      return;
    if (location.getProvider().equals(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
      tvLocationGPS.setText(formatLocation(location));
    }
  }

  private String formatLocation(Location location) {
    if (location == null)
      return "";
    return String.format(
            "Coordinates: lat = %1$.4f, lon = %2$.4f, time = %3$tF %3$tT",
            location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), new Date(
                    location.getTime()));
  }
  private void checkEnabled() {
    tvEnabledGPS.setText("Enabled: "
            + locationManager
            .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER));}
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.test.location">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**strings.xml**

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">Location</string>
    <string name="provider_gps">GPS</string>
    <string name="provider_network">Network</string>
    <string name="location_settings">Location settings</string>
    <string name="btnUpdate">btnUpdate</string>
</resources>
```

Comment: Возможно у вас маломощный девайс\маломощный комп не тянущий эмулятор. Или вы тестируете в помещении, где спутник не ловит. Или GPS модуль умирает. Если вы просто скопировали код примера, то врятли в нём дело.

Comment: А может просто дата выставлена на телефоне неверно + телефон находиться в помещении + выключен вайфай + нет интернета. И будет сутками искать.

Answer (score 1):

Рекомендую использовать [Google Play services location APIs](https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html?hl=ru) для определения местоположения. Хорошая статья на русском [здесь](https://habrahabr.ru/post/191290/).

Answer (score 0):

Можно для начала использовать этот метод :

```
/*@return the last know best location*/

private Location getLastBestLocation() {
Location locationGPS =      mLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
Location locationNet = mLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

long GPSLocationTime = 0;
if (null != locationGPS) { GPSLocationTime = locationGPS.getTime(); }

long NetLocationTime = 0;

if (null != locationNet) {
    NetLocationTime = locationNet.getTime();
}

if ( 0 < GPSLocationTime - NetLocationTime ) {
    return locationGPS;
}
else {
    return locationNet;
}
}
```

А после, когда координаты определятся через GPS_PROVIDER, использовать уже определенные им координаты.